# Active record column names convert to Array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using ruby on rails 5 .. I want get active record column names in array of hash Format..
e.g

```
Customer.column_names
=> ["id", "key", "name", "domain_name", "description"]
```

Now i want to convert this array to like

```
 [{"name"=>"id"}, {"name"=>"key"}, {"name"=>"name"}, {"name"=>"domain_name"}, {"name"=>"description"}]
```

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Check out [`#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to turn the elements into hashes:

```
result = Customer.column_names.map { |column| {"name" => column} }
#=> [{"name"=>"id"}, {"name"=>"key"}, {"name"=>"name"}, {"name"=>"domain_name"}, {"name"=>"description"}]
```

Comment: `{"name": column}` would result in `{:name=>"id"}`

Comment: You get symbolic keys, because `{"name": column}` is equivalent to `{ name: column }` which is equivalent to `{ :name => column }`. If you want strings, use `{ "name" => column }`. There's no need to call `as_json`.

Comment: Understood, thanks for explanation. Updated the answer :-)